# Como capturar pacotes de uma conexão TCP usando um proxy?

Tags: socket, conexão, proxy, dart, tcp

Estou escrevendo um Proxy TCP para capturar pacotes enviados do meu computador para um servidor remoto e vice-versa. Eu liguei um servidor falso de testes em localhost e o Proxy funciona bem, interceptando e direcionando os pacotes recebidos por um client, usando telnet, para o servidor de teste (no meu pc). O problema é que quando eu inicio o Proxy e conecto com o servidor remoto real, o Proxy não captura os pacotes dessa conexão. Como eu posso arrumar isso?

proxy.dart:

```dart
class Proxy {
  Proxy(String host, int port) {
    ServerSocket.bind(localhost, port).then((server) {
      print('Listening on $localhost:$port');
      server.listen((socket) async {
        print('Client connected to proxy');
        final clientConn = await Socket.connect(host /* localhost*/, port);

        final client2proxy = ClientToProxy(socket, clientConn);
        final proxy2server = ProxyToServer(clientConn, socket);
      });
    });
  }
}
```

client_to_proxy.dart:

```dart
class ClientToProxy {
  Socket socket;
  Socket remote;
  String address;
  int port;

  ClientToProxy(Socket sock, Socket rem) {
    socket = sock;
    remote = rem;
    address = socket.remoteAddress.address;
    port = socket.remotePort;
    msgPattern = '[client] ($address:$port) ->';

    socket.listen(onDataHandler,
        onError: onErrorHandler, onDone: onDoneHandler);
  }

  void onDataHandler(List<int> data) {
    if (debug) print('$msgPattern Data: ${String.fromCharCodes(data)}');
    pipeSocket(remote, data);
  }

  void pipeSocket(Socket sock, dynamic data) => sock.add(data);
}
```

proxy_to_server.dart:

```dart
class ProxyToServer {
  Socket socket;
  Socket remote;
  String address;
  int port;

  ProxyToServer(Socket sock, Socket rem) {
    socket = sock;
    remote = rem;
    address = socket.remoteAddress.address;
    port = socket.remotePort;
    msgPattern = '[server] ($address:$port) ->';

    socket.listen(onDataHandler,
        onError: onErrorHandler, onDone: onDoneHandler);
  }

  void onDataHandler(List<int> data) {
    if (debug) print('$msgPattern Data: ${String.fromCharCodes(data)}');
    pipeSocket(remote, data);
  }

  void pipeSocket(Socket sock, dynamic data) => sock.add(data);
}
```

Como eu deveria interceptar esses pacotes?

Comment: não conheço Dart, mas me parece que nesta linha "final clientConn = await Socket.connect(host /* localhost*/, port);" você precisa passar o ip do servidor remoto, onde está "/*localhost*/"

Comment: Na verdade eu já passo o IP do servidor remoto em "host", no caso o "localhost" está comentado.

Comment: verdade...será que não tem um firewalll em sua máquina ou na máquina remota bloqueando conexões ?

Comment: Acredito que não, acho que se bloqueasse a conexão, o socket lançaria uma exceção e terminaria a execução do programa. Talvez eu esteja esquecendo de alguma coisa relacionada ao protocolo TCP?

Answer (score 0):

Você está fazendo o bind apenas na interface localhost, tem que fazer o bind em todas as interfaces. Para isso usa-se o endereço ip 0.0.0.0.

```
class Proxy {
  Proxy(String host, int port) {
    // ServerSocket.bind(localhost, port).then((server) { // <-----------------
    ServerSocket.bind("0.0.0.0", port).then((server) {
      print('Listening on $localhost:$port');
      server.listen((socket) async {
        print('Client connected to proxy');
        final clientConn = await Socket.connect(host /* localhost*/, port);

        final client2proxy = ClientToProxy(socket, clientConn);
        final proxy2server = ProxyToServer(clientConn, socket);
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Obs. não testado, mas se houver erro provavelmente será na sintaxe do Dart.

Comment: Eu não mostrei no código, mas a variável ```localhost``` é definida como: ```final localhost = InternetAddress.anyIPv4.address; //isso retorna '0.0.0.0'```, o que já escuta conexões em todas as interfaces: ```Listening on 0.0.0.0:30009```

Comment: hmm...ok...mas vou deixar a resposta assim mesmo, por ser informativa

Comment: faça um teste com telnet da máquina client para seu programa rodando na máquina server...isso vai dirimir a dúvida se é o seu ambiente (no client ou mais provavelmente no server) que está barrando a conexão

Comment: ```Listening on 0.0.0.0:30000

Client connected to proxy

[client] (127.0.0.1:58930) -> Data: teste

[server] (52.45.64.113:30000) -> Disconnected / shut down
```

Tá meio difiicil de ler pelo comentário, mas basicamente: o socket do cliente (telnet) foi capturado no proxy, mas o servidor rejeita.

Comment: tá com jeito de ser firewall na máquina onde você roda o server (ou algum firewall intermediário, se for uma empresa)

Comment: faça um teste direto da máquina client para a máquina remota server, sem passar pelo proxy...se funcionar, então o erro é no proxy...se não funcionar, então o erro *não* é no proxy

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, o que faltava era redirecionar o host para o meu proxy no arquivo ```/etc/hosts``` do Linux.